# Google Fonts load really large for approx 1 second then render correctly, only in specific elements. Css issue?

Tags: html, css, google-webfonts

So I'm including the Lora Google font which generally works well however it appears that, on what we call 'static' content areas, when it's initially loaded it loads 2, maybe 3, times the size it should be rendered at for approximately 1 second then renders correctly. Has anyone noticed this behaviour?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example of this happening?

Comment: Hey Nit, yep sorry didn't know if I was able to post url's here. Check out www.healthmonthly.co.uk/help in Chrome, clicking various links on the left hand side to see font-size/line-height jumping about. The code is a culmination of 10+ years on a proprietary system, definitely isn't perfect and needs a complete overhaul!

Comment: Without going into detail, the problem is the baggage your site is carrying. Namely, a lot has been added (at rather random places) and little has been done in an orderly manner. There's random scripts in random places and content before and after those things. All that results in that your site needs to be repainted a number of times before it's finally displayed to the user: http://i.imgur.com/yhebHiF.png

Comment: Yep understand that a lot of elements are scattered throughout, unfortunately the result of many developers on a proprietary platform so I'm trying to optimise as much as possible in keeping with the wishes of higher powers :) The odd thing is, it doesn't happen on a product page, for example http://www.healthmonthly.co.uk/swanson_sup_herb_green_tea_ext_60